# Unique solution for $x = y + Tx$ if $T(x_1,x_2,\dots) = (\frac{1}{2}x_2,\frac{1}{3}x_3,\dots)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, operator-theory

**Exercise :**

> Let $T:\ell^\infty \to \ell^\infty$ be an operator such that :
>   $$T(x_1,x_2,\dots) = \bigg(\frac{1}{2}x_2,\frac{1}{3}x_3,\dots\bigg)$$
>   Show that for all $y \in \ell^\infty$, the equation 
>   $$x = y + Tx$$
>   has a unique solution.

**Attempt :**

I have proved that $T$ is a linear operator. Now, $\ell^\infty$ is the space defined as :
$$\ell^\infty = \{x =(x_n) : \|x\|< \infty\} \quad \|x\| :=\sup|x_n|$$
From the definition of the norm over $\ell^\infty$, we can observe that

$$\|T(x_1,x_2,\dots)\|<\|(x_1,x_2,\dots)\|$$

This means that there exists an $M<1$, such that :

$$\|T(x_1,x_2,\dots)\|\leq M\|(x_1,x_2,\dots)\|$$

Thus, $T$ is a bounded linear operator $T \in B(\ell^\infty)$ with $\|T\| \leq M <1$.

Now, it is

$$x = y + Tx \Leftrightarrow x-Tx = y \Leftrightarrow(1-T)x=y$$

where $1$ is the identity operator.

But $\ell^\infty$ is a Banach space and since $\|T\| <1$, then it is :

$$(1-T)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n \Leftrightarrow (1-T)^{-1}y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^ny$$

Thus $x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty T^ny$ is a unique solution to the equation $x=y+Tx$ for all $y \in \ell^\infty$.

**Question :** Is my approach correct and rigorous enough ?

Comment: You are correct and the proof looks sufficiently rigorous.  However, $\|T\|$ can be computed exactly.  That is, $\|T\|=\dfrac12$.

Comment: @Batominovski I guess that stems from the fact that $T(x_n) = \frac{x_{n+1}}{n+1}$ ?

Comment: Yes, see the answer below.

Comment: Oh, just one more thing.  I think the proof of existence of $M$ is a bit muddly.  I didn't see notice it at first.

Comment: @Batominovski Well, I think it's pretty straight-forward, since the norm of the argument is definitely bigger than the norm of the value yielded by the operator, since every sequence is divided and the first term is missing. But then, can't there be a $M \in \mathbb R$ such that when multiplied will yield an equal or bigger value ? Nonetheless, a more exact approach like yours is way more rigorous !

Comment: The thing is there are some cases where you have an operator $T$ such that $\big\|T(x)\big\|< M\|x\|$ for all $x\neq 0$, but it turns out that $\|T\|=M$.  See for example this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2997663/value-of-operator-norm-when-mathcaltfx-intx-0-ftdt.  The operator $\mathcal{T}$ in that example satisfies $\big\|\mathcal{T}(f)\big|<\|f\|$ for all nonzero $f\in\mathcal{C}$, but $\|\mathcal{T}\|=1$ (it is not proven there, but it is not too difficult to show that the equality does not happen unless $f\equiv 0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct and the proof looks sufficiently rigorous.  However, $\|T\|_\text{op}$ can be computed exactly.  That is, $\|T\|_\text{op}=\dfrac12$. To show this, let $z=(z_1,z_2,z_3,\ldots)\in\ell^\infty$. Then,
$$T(z)=\left(\frac{z_2}{2},\frac{z_3}{3},\frac{z_4}{4},\ldots\right)$$
so that
$$\big\|T(z)\big\|_{\infty}=\sup\left\{\frac{|z_k|}{k}\,\Big|\,k=2,3,4,\ldots\right\}\leq \sup\left\{\frac{\|z\|_\infty}{k}\,\Big|\,k=2,3,4,\ldots\right\}=\frac{\|z\|_\infty}{2}\,.$$
Note that the equality holds for $z=(0,1,0,0,0,\ldots)$.  This implies $\|T\|_{\text{op}}= \dfrac{1}{2}$.

You can write an explicit solution $x\in\ell^\infty$ to $x=y+T(x)$.  That is, $$x=(1-T)^{-1}y=\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,\frac{y_k}{k!},\sum_{k=2}^\infty\,\frac{2!y_k}{k!},\sum_{k=3}^\infty\,\frac{3!y_k}{k!},\ldots\right)$$
Nonetheless, you did sufficient and good work.  I was just making additional comments.