# Norm of Volterra Operator with $L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to find the Operator norm for the following operator

$$(Vf)(t):(C[0,1],L^1)\to (C[0,1],L^1)$$
$$f\mapsto \int_0^t f(s)ds$$

What I have done
$$\|Vf(t)\|=\sup_{\|f\|_{L^1}=1}{\|\int_0^t f(s) \|ds}_{L^1}=\sup_{\|{f}\|_{L^1}=1}\int_0^1|{\int_0^t f(s)| ~ds}dt\leq \sup_{\|{f}\|_{L^1}=1}\int_0^1\int_0^t |{f(s)}|~dsdt   .$$
Tonelli:
$$=\sup_{\|{f}\|_{L^1}=1}\int_0^t\int_0^1 |f(s)|~ dt ds =\sup_{\|{f}\|_{L^1}=1}\int_0^t |f(s)|~ds \leq \int_0^1|f(s)|~ds =\|{f}\|_{L^1}=1 $$

this doesnt seem all too correct. How do I continue?

Comment: Is $V$ a map on $C[0,1]$ or $L^1$? Your notation is very confusing.

Comment: If your notation means that V is acting on the space $C[0,1]$ equipped with the $L^1$ norm, then this question is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2997663/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\|V\|\leq 1$ is correct. To get $\|V\|\geq 1$ define $f_n(s)=nI_{(0,\frac 1 n)}$. (For each $s$, the function $f_n(s)$ is a constant function in $L^{1}$). I leave it to you to compute $Vf_n$.